# Copy simple text from webpage and paste in excel in Selenium webdriver using VBA

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

I need to copy a simple text (date) from a web page and then paste it to a cell in Excel.

```html
<input name="txtData" type="text" value="16/05/2023" maxlength="200" size="1" id="txtData"
       disabled="disabled" class="cssInputText" 
       onkeypress="javascript:passaCampo(event,txtHoraIni);"
       style="width:73px;">
```

This is what I've tried to write:

```vb
'Estabelece o destino da data
Dim destino_data_ase As Range
Set destino_data_ase = destino.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 2)

'Colocar a data
Dim dataase As WebElement
Set dataase = cd.FindElementByCss("#txtData")
                
destino_data_ase.Select
'Comando para colar
            
i = i + 1
cd.GoBack
```